# Error in LSTM model: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>

This is the error.

my coding is below:

```
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                                                  patience=2, mode='min')

model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
             optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
             metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=50,
                             validation_data=test_generator,
                             shuffle=False,
                             callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

I think it is regarding my data (train_generator):

```
win_length = 1
batch_size = 12
num_features = 4
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_train, y_train, length=win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch_size)
test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_test, y_test, length=win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch_size
```

My train_generator data look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try install tf 2.4.0 and keras 2.4.3 versions

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.4.0
!pip install keras==2.4.3
```